# Which AppStoreConnect option to use for IAPs Tip Jar

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I want to add a `TipJar` to my apps using the [TipJarViewController pod](https://github.com/lionheart/TipJarViewController)

In the instructions for the pod it says:

> Before you can use TipJarViewController in your app, you'll
>   first need to create a few IAPs in iTunes Connect--2 subscription IAPs
>   and 5 one-time IAPs.

Which `AppStoreConnect` option to choose for **one-time IAPs** so that the user can leave a tip?

I was going to select **Non-Consumable** but it says:

> A product that is purchased once and does not expire or decrease with
>   use

Wouldn't a one time tip expire? It's not very clear even though Apple now [allows tip jars](https://techcrunch.com/2017/06/09/in-app-tips/). I'd expect it to have an option for "tips or donations"

[image]

I would've asked the pod author but sometimes they take a while to respond and I'm sure other devs on here would eventually have the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I choose **Consumable** because it's only used once and depleted